# Dask pandas apply freezes and ultimately gets killed

Tags: pandas, parallel-processing, dask

I paralellized my `pandas.apply` with a `dask.map_paritions` and it works fine on a test DataFrame (600 rows) cutting my calculations from 6 to 2 minutes - computing inner function as expected.

However, when I run the full set (6000 rows) the code gest irrepsponsive, the CPU and memory seems to be loaded and ultimately gets killed:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd        
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=params.parallel)
applied = ddf.map_partitions(lambda dframe: dframe.apply(lambda x: my_fun(inData, x), axis=1)).compute(scheduler='processes')
```

after 15 minutes (BTW simple pandas.apply on the full dataset takes ca 15 minutes) I get from the console:

```
Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
```

I am running MacOS, python 3.7, calling from PyCharm - any hints?

PS. I tried both few partitions (2,4) and a lot (32 - since I though maybe that's memory issue)

PS2. I pass quite big objects in `inData` to my `apply function` in classic pandas it does not matter, since it is linear, here I think maybe that is an issue (since I have there e.g. a network graph of ca 700MB) - can it be?

Comment: Recommend that you try with the distributed scheduler running locally rather than "processes". It is more intelligent about not repeating work and can give you better diagnostics.

Comment: "I pass quite big objects in inData", agreed, you want to "scatter" this probably, and have it as a function argument rather than in the closure.

Comment: @mdurant - so which 'scheduler' you suggest to pass instead of 'processes'?

Comment: The distributed scheduler, as I said: http://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/